# Deleting duplicate rows in large database throws error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a rather large set of data (about 10 million rows) with many duplicates. To delete these duplicates, I use this query (which - from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows) - I understand to be the most efficient):

```
;WITH cte
  AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1, COL2, COL3 
    ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
  FROM MYTABLE)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE RN > 1
```

The server is returning this error:

**The transaction log for database 'ABC' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases**

How can I get around this problem and delete the duplicate rows?

Comment: truncate the log more ften.

Comment: Place this log on another drive or add a second log on another drive. If not possible truncate log and replace `from mytable` by `from (select top 1000000 * from mytable) M` and try to run this query as long as no rows are deleted anymore. After each run truncate log. For better solution post create table.

Answer (score 0):

A perennial problem. DELETE is a logged action and past experience has shown me that the log can grow to be bigger than the data file when a lot of data is deleted. A good solution, but not applicable in all circumstances, is to copy the data you want to keep to a new table, drop the original table then rename to new table back to the original. Clearly this would have to be done during a period of maintenance when the database isn't being used.

Hey Microsoft: how about a non-logged DELETE

Comment: TRUNCATE doesn't support a WHERE clause. It also resets the IDENTITY attribute